# Как отлепить рамки картинок друг от друга?

Tags: html, css

случилась такая проблема, что не могу отсоединить 2 ряда фотографий в рамках. Вот есть 2 ряда фотографий по горизонтали и их рамки слиплись. Не подскажите, как сделать между ними расстояние?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.row{
width: 900px;
}
.pic3{
border: 3px solid #blue;
padding: 12px;
}

<div class="row4">
            <div class="photo1 pic3">
                <img src="images/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="photo2 pic3">
                <img src="images/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="photo3 pic3">
                <img src="images/3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="photo4 pic3">
                <img src="images/4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="photo5 pic3">
                <img src="images/5.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="photo6 pic3">
                <img src="images/6.jpg">
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: всё, ребят, не нужно. нашел ответ. нужно прописать - margin: 10 auto. или с другим любым числом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

margin: [значение | проценты];